# Unexpected ">>>" above the table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<h2 id="notice"><%= notice %></h2>
<h1>Cars</h1>

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>License-plate Number</th>
    <th>Manufactuere</th>
    <th>Model</th>
    <th>Hourly Rental Rate</th>
    <th>Style</th>
    <th>Location</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th colspan="3"></th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
```

I met this weird problem long before, but cannot remember how I solved it. Could anyone tell you what to do.

Comment: You should show us more code if want some help. There is no problem with your code. Those arrows are appearing somewhere else. Show us more, like partial views and application.html.

Comment: <tbody>
  <% @cars.each do |car| %>
      <% if login_authority.eql? 'customer' %>
          <% if car.status.eql? 'Available' %>
              <tr>
                <td><%= car.lpn %></td>

Comment: @MatiasSeguel Hi Matias, the rest of the file is some tbody code, I put some of it here. Stackoverflow does not allow me to put all the code.

Comment: Add a repository.